# How to filter d3.nested data in javascript - nested function

Tags: javascript, function, d3.js

I am trying to filter to get value by nested data
so if my input is ...
[image]

currently I use the code below to get **b** from **maximum a** for each name ( christine, smiths, aaron ) .
But I am trying to get value **b** where **a = 2** for each name  ( christine, hannah, jeannie)

```
  var names = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .entries(data);

   names.forEach(function(n) {
    n.maxAValue = d3.max(n.values, function(d) { return d.b; });
                             });
```

the above works fine, but I was trying to get value where a == 2  with something like this below. Is there a way I could do something like this in javascript ?

```
names.forEach(function(n) { n.values, 
       function(d) { if(d.a == 2) { return d.b; }  }
                          });
```

======Edit======

```
data = [
  {
    "name":"apple",
    "a":1,
    "b":"jame"
  },
  {
    "name":"apple",
    "a":2,
    "b":"christine"
  },
  {
    "name":"orange",
    "a":1,
    "b":"nick"
  },
  {
    "name":"orange",
    "a":2,
    "b":"hannah"
  },
  {
    "name":"orange",
    "a":3,
    "b":"smiths"
  },
  {
    "name":"peach ",
    "a":1,
    "b":"boo"
  },
  {
    "name":"peach ",
    "a":2,
    "b":"jeannie"
  },
  {
    "name":"peach ",
    "a":3,
    "b":"aaron"
  }
]
```

Comment: To filter data in any kind of way, I like to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/), it helps a lot with array manipulation.

Comment: @HuguesStefanski can you show me exactly how to do this in my case, i 'm fairly new to javascript. ..

Comment: Would you happpen to have your data in json format? Or maybe a plunk/jsbin already?

Comment: @HuguesStefanski just added data = json

Comment: Plnkr using lodash: http://plnkr.co/edit/PfgQjwAmbz4JxTyZBxaB?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in array.filter function for this:

```
var filtered = data.filter(function(d) {
   return d.a == 2; 
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates this in action and then uses d3 to bind the filtered data to an HTML ul:

http://jsfiddle.net/bywdq375/1/